# ListView not filling up when I try to fill it from another page using MessagingCenter to comunicate both classes

Tags: c#, xamarin, mobile, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I'm trying to fill up or populate a ListView that is instantiated in PageA when the user clicks a button in PageB. I'm doing it sending a message with the MessageCenter in PageB and calling the MessageCenter.Subscribe() method in PageA (the Page where I want to add the new ViewCell or row to the ListView)... but it's not working.

I don't think that the problem is coming from the send/subscribe usage because I have alredy debugged the application and the collection that i'm passing to the ListiView.ItemSource property is indeed growning in size. Here you can see the class definitions:

PageA class definition:

```
public partial class WorkoutRoutineTab : ContentPage
    {
        public List<Routine> Routines { get; set; } = new List<Routine>();

        public WorkoutRoutineTab()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            routineListView.ItemsSource = Routines;

            MessagingCenter.Subscribe<AddExercisePage, Routine>(this, "FillRoutines", (messageSender, arg) =>
            {
                Routines.Add(new Routine(arg.Name, arg.ExerciseList));
                routineListView.ItemsSource = Routines;
            });
        }

        private async void NewRoutineButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await DisplayAlert("ALERT", Routines.Count.ToString() , "ok");
            await Navigation.PushAsync(new ExerciseBankTab() { Title = "" });
        }
```

PageA .xaml file:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PumpFit"
             xmlns:custom="clr-namespace:PumpFit.Entity"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="PumpFit.WorkoutRoutineTab"
             Title="Workout"
             BackgroundColor="#343434">

    <StackLayout x:Name="routineStackLayout" Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" Margin="20,10">
        <ListView x:Name="routineListView" x:FieldModifier="public" SeparatorColor="#2C2C2C">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <Grid RowDefinitions="2*,*" ColumnDefinitions="*,*">
                            <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Text="{Binding custom:Name}" TextColor="White" FontSize="Large" FontFamily="Ubuntu"/>
                            <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding custom:TimesDone}" TextColor="#9F9F9F" FontSize="Body" FontFamily="Ubuntu"/>
                            <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding custom:TimesDone}" TextColor="#9F9F9F" FontSize="Body" FontFamily="Ubuntu"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
            <Button x:Name="newRoutineButton" Text="New routine" FontSize="Body" FontFamily="Geo" 
                BackgroundColor="#2C2C2C" TextColor="#87BC72" Clicked="NewRoutineButton_Clicked" />
    </StackLayout> 

</ContentPage>
```

PageB class definition:

```
public partial class AddExercisePage : ContentPage
    {
        public Exercise newExercise;

        public AddExercisePage(Exercise selectedExercise)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            newExercise = selectedExercise; 

            nameLabel.Text = newExercise.Name;
        }

        private async void CancelButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await Navigation.PopModalAsync();
        }

        private void AddButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(setsEntry.Text != null && repsEntry.Text != null && restTimePicker.SelectedItem != null)
            {
                if (int.TryParse(setsEntry.Text, out int sets) && int.TryParse(repsEntry.Text, out int reps) && sets > 0 && reps > 0)
                {
                    List<Exercise> newExerciseList = new List<Exercise>()
                    {
                        new Exercise(newExercise.Name, newExercise.MuscleGroup, newExercise.ExerciseDifficulty, newExercise.Equipment, newExercise.Description, sets, reps, restTimePicker.SelectedItem.ToString())
                    };

                    MessagingCenter.Send<AddExercisePage, Routine>(this, "FillRoutines", new Routine(routineNameEntry.Text, newExerciseList));
                }
                else
                {
                    DisplayAlert("ERROR", "You must only enter positive numbers", "OK");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                DisplayAlert("ERROR", "All fields must be set to add the exercise to the routine", "OK");
            }
        }
    }
```

ANY HELP WILL BE APRECCIATE IT! :v

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you're using

```
public List<Routine> Routines { get; set; } = new List<Routine>();
```

Change it to :

```
public ObservableCollection<Routine> Routines { set; get; } = new ObservableCollection<Routine>();
```

Both `List` and `ObservableCollection` implement `IList<T>`, there isn't much of a difference there, `ObservableCollection` also implements `INotifyCollectionChanged` interface.So it will update the Ui automatically when the collection changes.

Comment: Your are totally right, indeed that was the problem! Thanks a lot @Leo Zhu. I think that is better to use other collections than the generic List<> when your working with data that must update often right?

Comment: Zhu the problem re-appeared. I literally don't have changed those files since you answer the question and everything was working fine. but know it's not working! I don't know what the heck happened could you help me?

Comment: Try to let your messagingcenter subscribe with WorkoutRouineTab .

Comment: No luck, it stills the same and when subscribing with WorkoutRoutineTab the size of the ObservableCollection that I'm passing to the ItemSource property is not even growning in size. If I understand well, when you're telling me to subscribe with WorkoutRoutineTab is Just changing the first generic argument of the subscribe method, right? Just confirming, but anyway...still not working :'(

Comment: It's pretty weird, I mean the only new thing that I made since it was working is adding a new content page that i'm pushing in the navigation stack when any item of the ListView is tapped, but it is in a completely different event, I don't even touched the rest of the code. Do you wanna see the other class?